# Case Insensitive search in oracle 12g

Tags: sql, oracle, select, sql-like, case-insensitive

I have count query, which should counts the total number of records corresponding to the displayed list, I am using `like` to filter out the record by matching the freetext, record exists in the table but still, query count is 0.

What I did, I supplied the text **abc** in the search box, but inside table the data is stored in the uppercase i,e **ABC**.

I want a method for case insensitive search.

QUERY:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(calender_id)
FROM
    calender s
    LEFT JOIN userdetail uu ON update_by = uu.user_id
WHERE
    calender_id = calender_id
     AND LOWER(s.details) LIKE 'Abc%'
```

Comment: A lowercase column value can't be like something that contains an uppercase letter.

Comment: `calender_id = calender_id` ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below

```
SELECT
    COUNT(calender_id)
FROM
    calender s
    LEFT JOIN userdetail uu ON update_by = uu.user_id
WHERE
    calender_id = calender_id
     AND LOWER(s.details) LIKE lower('Abc')||'%'
```

Comment: how do I include both upper and lower case, because user can supply any input from the GUI

Comment: You don't need to look for both uppercase and lowercase like this.  One or the other would do.

Answer (score 4):

Since you're `lower`ing the table's column, you should use a lowercase literal too:

```
LOWER(s.details) LIKE 'abc%'
-- Here ---------------^
```

Answer (score 3):

for the case insensitive the easiest way is using the lower or upper, I think you should modify the query in this way:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(calender_id)
FROM
    calender s
    LEFT JOIN userdetail uu ON update_by = uu.user_id
WHERE
    calender_id = calender_id
     AND LOWER(s.details) LIKE 'abc%'
```

or

```
SELECT
    COUNT(calender_id)
FROM
    calender s
    LEFT JOIN userdetail uu ON update_by = uu.user_id
WHERE
    calender_id = calender_id
     AND UPPER(s.details) LIKE 'ABC%'
```